# I want to insert a ForeignKey in users Table but it inserted as null with fortify in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-fortify

I added a foreignKey column o specify a role for the **user**.
This is **users** table : *before I add **nullable()** to **role_id** column they were told me that the **role_id** column has no default value, and when I add **nullable()** they insert the NULL value to the table*

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
    $table->string('email')->unique()->nullable();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

and this is **roles** table:

```
Schema::create('roles', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

This is the blade code for **role** column:
*I've added an array on the blade to show its content in the option tag with attribute name of "**role_id**" as you see in my blade code*

```
@php
    $role_array = ['employee', 'client'];
@endphp

<div class="form-group row">
    <label for="role" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Role <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="role" name="role_id" class=" form-control">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            @foreach ($role_array as $x => $x_value)
                 <option value="{{++$x}}">{{$x_value}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is The **create** method on "**CreateNewUser.php**" file:

```
    public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => [
                'string',
                'email',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'phone_number' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:10',
                'max:13',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'role_id' => [
                'required',
                Rule::unique(User::class),
            ],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),

        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

This is the **User** Model:

```
   protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'password',
        'phone_number',
        'email',
        'role_id',
    ];
```

Comment: what's your problem? and what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to pass `role_id` to create method

```
   return User::create([
            'name' => $input['name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'phone_number' => $input['phone_number'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
            'role_id' => $input['role_id'],
        ]);
```

Also for roles in controller

```
$role_array=Role::pluck('type','id');
```

Then in view

```
<select id="role" name="role_id" class=" form-control">
            <option selected>Choose...</option>
            @foreach ($role_array as $x => $x_value)
                 <option value="{{$x}}">{{$x_value}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
```

Comment: Thanks I it solved it, the problem was in the create method as you said